# How to install qpdfview 0.4.14?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, tar

I have been using the 0.4.12 build for a couple of months now and am ready to update to 0.4.14. I've tried a couple of things to install it but for fear of screwing up my Trusty environment I thought I would ask the experts here.

What I've tried (using terminal):

- unpacked the targz file
- cd to Downloads
- cd archive name
- then tried ./configure which did not work
- looked in the README file and found the instructions a bit vague for my level of linux understanding

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure if this is too late but you can simply add and install the qpdfview PPA with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:b-eltzner/qpdfview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qpdfview
```

Comment: I got `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~b-eltzner/ubuntu/qpdfview'.
ERROR: '~b-eltzner' user or team does not exist.`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install qpdfview` still worked

Answer (score 6):

As you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview/+packages), `qpdfview` 0.4.14 is part of the "universe" repository from 15.10 onwards. So, as long as you have that repository enabled, you can simply install with

```
sudo apt-get install qpdfview
```

Also, you can always check the version available for your distro using `apt-cache policy <package_name>`. You will get something like this:

```
lucho@lucho-HP:~$ apt-cache policy qpdfview
qpdfview:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.14-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.14-1 500
        500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of qpdfview (0.4.18beta1 at this time) are always available at the developer's PPA. These daily are builds, and should not be considered stable, but I've had no issues so far:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adamreichold/qpdfview-dailydeb
sudo apt update
```

Just make sure you have removed any previous versions using

```
sudo apt remove qpfview
```

before installing using the usual `sudo apt install qpfview`