# How can I install evince 3.14?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, pdf, evince

My current version is 3.10. The annotation can't delete, and I want the newest stable version to be installed. Here is a related post: [How can I install the latest version of Evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310974/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-evince)

Also, I can't find go to the previous postion menu. It is a very useful one, how can I add it. [Document Viewer (Evince) history navigation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330105/document-viewer-evince-history-navigation)

I've searched the web, but find no answer.

ps: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Based on these mentioned instructions ([How can I install the latest version of Evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310974/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-evince)) you have added the PPA `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`.

This package contains (currently) no version of `evince`.

The most recent version, you can install in Ubuntu 14.04 is version 3.12. For version 3.16 you need Ubuntu 15.04.

---

You have to add the PPA `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`. But remember that GNOME is completely updated to v3.12.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

From the PPA description:

> This PPA will be used to test uploads before they are copied to the
>   main GNOME 3 PPA.

and the PPA `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`, which you've already added.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

After you start the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I've just done so, but only to discover that v3.12 does not support note deletion, either.

Answer (score 5):

Actually I just found that `qpdfview` is a very good, light-weighted pdfviewer have everything I need.

It support highlight, go backwards, addd anotation, many keyboard short cuts. You can find how to install it here: [How to install qpdfview 0.4.14?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590708/how-to-install-qpdfview-0-4-14)

**Have a try.** This is the best pdfviewer I found so far!

Answer to my original question is still very welcomed.

Comment: Here is an introduction :http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/04/qpdfview-pdf-reader-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Oh, at last I change to wine+ foxit reader. I hope native pdf reader in linux can develop faster.

Comment: Good alternative +1